# Focus in apex:ActionSupport don't work

Tags: visualforce

I want to focus selectList or inputText.
So, I use focus attributes in apex:ActionSupport.
But, this don't work.
What should I do?

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" docType="html-5.0" id="page" >
<apex:form onkeydown="return NoSubmit(event);" >
    <div id="all">
        <div id="form">
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <div>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="conservPanels">
                        <apex:pageBlock >
                            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Select List"/>
                                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectValue}" size="1">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SampleOptions}"/>
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!decideListType}" focus="sampleText" />
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </apex:pageBlock>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:pageBlock>
                        <apex:pageBlockSection>
                            <apex:input  />
                            <apex:input id="sampleText" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:pageBlock>                        
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </div>

</apex:form>
<script type="text/javaScript">
beenFocused = true;
</script>
```

Apex Class

```
    public without sharing class SampleController {

    public String selectValue{get;set;}

    // コンストラクタ
    public SampleController(){
        this.selectValue = '';
    }

    public PageReference decideListType(){
        //save selectValue and so on

        return null;
    }

    /**
*Select List
*/    
    public  List<SelectOption> getSampleOptions(){
        //選択リスト作成
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('sample1','sample1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('sample2','sample2'));

        return options;
    }



}
```

Comment: try adding reRender= to the actionSupport

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding reRender. But 
`public PageReference decideListType` don't work.